# Fix a user to its specific blog when logged in

Tags: python, django

Here is my view for blog_create. I want to fix this for a specific user when he/she is logged in.

```
@login_required
def blog_create(request,blogger_id):
    blog=Blog.objects.all()
    user=get_object_or_404(User,pk=blogger_id)

form=BlogForm(request.POST)
if request.method=="GET":
    return render(request,'winterblog/blog_create.html',{'form':form})
if request.method=="POST":
    if form.is_valid():
        blog=form.save(commit=False)
        blog.save()
        return redirect('winterblog:blog_list')
    else:
        form=BlogForm()
        return redirect('winterblog:blog_create')
```

And for the form is:

```
class BlogForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model=Blog
    fields=['headline','blog_text','user']
```

[image: Fix the user to admin here.]

Thanks!

Comment: What you wanted to fix it.? Do you want to save the form without error ?

Comment: This question is not clear. What does "Fix a user to its specific blog when logged in" mean? Does the site have multiple blogs on multiple URLs and you want a user to always go to their own blog? Or do you want the new post to go to the correct blog? Or... ? Please clarify.

Comment: To the user who is currently logged in. Here admin is. Right now I have to manually select the user.

Answer (score 0):

Hide user from your modelform field

```
class BlogForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Blog
        fields=['headline','blog_text']
```

And assign user after form.save will help

```
if request.method=="POST":
    if form.is_valid():
        blog=form.save(commit=False)
        blog.user = request.user
        blog.save()
```